# Не знаю как расположить api и фронтэнд в задании

Tags: javascript, postgresql, redux, reactjs, express

Добрый день, есть тестовое задание в котором некоторые нюансы мне не понятны. Был бы рад если б кто-то подсказал:

- api и сервер с React/Redux должны быть на отдельных серверах, если просят два репозитория?
- "Результаты запросов должны храниться в store"... Понятно что сами запросы это экшены, но результаты каким образом сохранять в сторе? Создавать отдельны редюсер и диспатчить экшн когда результат запроса приходит, а сам результат сохранять?

> Тестовое задание:
>
> Нужно сделать регистрацию с логинкой используя JWT. Регистрация с
>   полями: имя, пароль, емейл. Логин: емейл, пароль. На дашборде список
>   товаров, товар можно создать, удалить,  редактировать. Товар с полями:
>   имя, количество и два статуса для него: на складе, в пути. Когда
>   открываешь редактирование товара, под формой логи: Товар был создан
>   ${имя создателя}, Товар был отредактирован ${имя}, Статус товара был
>   изменен ${имя}. На дашборде для каждого товара должно выводиться
>   последний лог товара и кем был создан товар, его имя и статус.
>
> Два репозитория один для фронтенда, второй для апи. Все данные на
>   фронтенде должны проходить через Redux, результаты запросов так же
>   должны храниться в store, сам запрос это экшен. База данных: Postgres
>   в nodejs использовать knex.js для связи с базой. На сервере не должно
>   быть циклов, не одного. Все это залить на heroku и в конце прислать
>   ссылку на github/bitbucket/gitlab и heroku.

Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: Ничего себе у них тестовые задания! Вообще-то это больше похоже на часть работы, за которую они не хотят платить.

Comment: И действительно, что это за тестовое? Задача на несколько дней! А если тестовое более 4 часов пусть оплачивают!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> api и сервер с React/Redux должны быть на отдельных серверах, если просят два репозитория?

1. 2 независимых репозитория: один для FE, второй для BE.
2. Каждый репозиторий должен содержать код http-сервера, выполняющего поставленную перед ним задачу (api и сайт).
3. Сайт при помощи кроссдоменных запросов обращается к api.

По крайней мере, я так думаю.

> "Результаты запросов должны храниться в store"... Понятно что сами запросы это экшены, но результаты каким образом сохранять в сторе? Создавать отдельны редюсер и диспатчить экшн когда результат запроса приходит, а сам результат сохранять?

Выглядит логично.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то все таки React клиент будет находится на отдельном сервере отличном от API?

Comment: @RomanSarder, физический сервер может быть одним и тем же, но http-сервера разные. Т. е., как вариант, они расположены на одном сервере, но слушают разные порты.

Comment: однако на Heroku я слыхал что два порта открыть нельзя.

Comment: @RomanSarder, не в курсе.

Answer (score 2):

1. Думаю, они имеют в виду, что вам нужно хранить фронтовую часть и api на разных git-репозиториях, чтобы им было это удобней потом использовать. Сервер у вас, конечно, будет один, просто, когда вы будете собирать свой проект придется в package.json указать фронтовый репозиторий в качестве dependency.
2. Redux предполагает наличие одного store в котором хранятся все стейты ваших компонентов, образуя тем самым глобальный стейт вашего приложения. Если вы в ответ на экшн изменяете стейт какого-нибудь компонента, то он автоматически попадает в store.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как потом интегрировать подключенный фронт репозиторий в api...

Comment: Физический да, но http-серверов, вероятно, два.